# Plotting a hierarchically indexing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, hierarchical-data

Consider the following code:

```
col_indices = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2], ['a', 'b']])
row_indices = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=row_indices, columns=col_indices)
```

When I plot this, I get five legend entries including one which says None, None:

[image]

Why is this, and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can remove it putting:

```
df.columns.names = ['', '']
```

Or if you would like something to appear there:

```
df.columns.names = ['name1', 'name2']
```

The labels are the names of the levels of the multiindex of the DataFrame.

**Option 2**

add:

```
plt.legend()
```

after the plotting command. You need to have "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" at the top of code.